# Joining attribute by location failing to join all attributes

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have a polygon representing an urban area. I have point data representing the cities which fall in this urban area. I'm trying to combine both polygon and points using a "join attributes by location". When I do so, only one point out of the 11 points appear in the attribute table. Any insight on what I may be doing wrong?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do all layers have the same CRS?

Comment: @MrXsquared Yes!

Comment: Try performing the join in the other direction, ie joining the polygon layer to the point layer.

Comment: What are you selecting for your attribute summary? You may want to reverse the order...i.e., set the cities as the target layer and the urban area as the join layer. This way, you can retain all attributes for all features.

Comment: please add (and accept) your solution as an answer for future searchers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing the join attribute by location the other way around (selecting polygon as "target vector layer" and point data as "join vector layer"). Therefore, only one city out of the 11 was added to the attribute table.
Doing this the other way around gave me point data within the polygon with all the information needed.